# Strange noise (whistle) from PC

Tags: desktop-computer, noise

I often hear a strange noise from my computer. It sounds like a whistle or a tick-tack from a cricket bug.

You can hear it on this video: https://vimeo.com/143945875

What can be the possible reason?

It happens very often, even after turning the PC on. I suppose it shouldn't be anything with the heat as the fan works and the computer isn't even warm when the sounds happens.

Comment: To me, it sounds like vibration coming from one of your fans. Have you cleaned dust out of the inside of your PC recently? How old are your fans, and have you replaced them at one point?

Comment: It sounds like a squeaky fan bearing to me.

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned the dust from the inside today but the sound still happens.
The PC is 1.5 year old.

Comment: The video did not play for me)

Answer (score 1):

Fans wear out over time, and noises like that *certainly* sound like a fan.

Since its a proper desktop, with fairly standard user serviceable parts, there's a few options.

If your motherboard has a fan control application, it may have an option to turn fans to full speed one by one. ALternately, if its supported you can use something like speedfan to do the same.

Turn up fans one by one to 100%, and turn off the other fans. Listen. If you have sounds stop when a fan is stopped that's the fan. A new fan is definately worth the few dollars it costs (and a nice one means even more slience).

If its not the fan, *listen*, locate the sound and find out what's the part. You're not going to learn what's the cause without cracking open the cases.